# Karaf unresolved constraint JDBC

Tags: scala, jdbc, osgi, h2, apache-karaf

I am trying to get a Scala library using H2 database loading in Karaf 3.0.0-RC1 and I got this error

```
Unresolved constraint in bundle org.h2 [86]: Unable to resolve 86.0: missing requirement 
[86.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.jdbc)(version>=1.0.0)
```

Does anyone know what I need to add to POM and / or feature.xml to get this working?

Thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need that jar that contains the package. To get it:

- go to http://search.maven.org
- Push Advanced search
- To the Classname, type "org.osgi.service.jdbc"

You will get a list of dependencies that contain the package. For example, the first one will be good for you: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.ow2.spec.osgi|ow2-jdbc-service-1.0-spec|1.0.13|bundle

Btw.: The package originally comes from the OSGi enterprise spec (or compendium, do not remember). As much as I saw all of the OSGi spec packages are available in ow2 dependencies that separated logically.

In Karaf, there might be other ways to get the dependency you need but I did not use Karaf in the past.

Comment: Thanks, I actually found it in OSGi enterprise package as you also suggested.